# How to edit pastebin post from bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

How I can edit existing pastebin post with bash script? I can upload text with script but every time create new paste (with same name but different address).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to download the paste bin file and edit on your system and upload it when you're finished. If you use nano, one possibility would be to do the following:

```bsh
wget -O pastebinfile #https://www.pastebin.com/address/to/paste/bin 
nano pastebinfile
#upload command
```